# "PrimeFaces is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, printing

I am trying to print using the PrimeFaces printer functionality. I have created a new GlassFish 3 Java EE project and added the PrimeFaces 3.1.1 `.jar` file.

The code I am using currently is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <h:form>
      <h:outputText id="a" value="AA" />
      <h:commandLink id="btn" value="Print">
        <p:printer target="a" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the print function isn't working. Instead, the FireBug console shows me the following error:

> PrimeFaces is not defined

Comment: do u have `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">` at the top??

Comment: Do you have any javascript code defined?

Comment: yeah I have html and I dont have any javascript defined

Comment: Make sure you added <h:head> </h:head> in your xhtml file

Answer (score 19):

If you didnt have a head tag you will get that error.

Primefaces requires a head tag to work.

See #2 on their faq

http://primefaces.org/faq.html

Comment: Yep that was definitely it for me.

Comment: I had <head> instead of <h:head>
Changing which solved my problem and my UI pretty much sorted itself neatly

Answer (score 6):

This was a minor defect and fixed in 3.2. final;

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3670

Answer (score 5):

This will also happen if you are not allowing access to

${webapp}/javax.faces.resources/**

Check your security XML configuration.

The JavaScript error that Primefaces is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

try this... (if this does not work its probably a bug - open a ticket on issue tracker...)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

    <h:head>  

    </h:head>  

    <h:body>  
     <h:form>
      <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Print">
        <p:printer target="output" />
      </h:commandButton>
      <h:outputText id="output" value="PrimeFaces Rocks!" />

      <h:outputLink id="lnk" value="#">
          <p:printer target="image" />
          <h:outputText value="Print Image" />
      </h:outputLink>
      <p:graphicImage id="image" value="/images/nature1.jpg" />

      </h:form>   
    </h:body>  
</html>
```

listen... primefaces are using the jqprint jquery plugin.... You might be better try use it directly while waiting for a official primefaces response...

Comment: I got this error : PrimeFaces is not defined
http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development
Line 2186

Comment: I think problem is something else, because this problem is strange

Comment: I tried using <p:dataTable /> <p:password /> and <p:fileUpload /> all are working except <p:printer /> hm...

Comment: yeah, its not working as well, have u tried to run that code ? if its not working even to u I am gonna add this to the issue tracker

Comment: same here(not working with 3.0 version)... listen primefaces are using the jqprint jquery plugin.... You might be better try use it directly while waiting for a official primefaces response...

Comment: just a guess. i once had a similar issue with primefaces calendar and curiously it worked if i added a second (not rendered) calendar on top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the PrimeFaces namespace.

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Have a look at [the PrimeFaces Getting Started guide](http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem if I only use a p:calendar on a form. All tags on the view are jsf/facelet tags. The only primefaces tag is the calendar. It looks as if the java-script is removed as an optimization ?

If I add more tags as a p:dataTable the java script errors disappear and the calendar component works. Perhaps this will point you some where. As a workaround you could a p:dataTable on the form with rendered=false.

Comment: Just upgrade to latest. In older versions, some components are missing a `@ResourceDependency` on `primefaces.js`. Otherwise, you can always explicitly include it by `<h:outputScript>`.

Comment: I'm having the problem on Primefaces 3.4

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag at the top of the jsf page and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, where the `PrimeFaces` variable has been used in my own script.

Here is what I did:

The variable `PrimeFaces` is defined in `core.js` of primefaces library.

Look at the source of the webpage in browser (e.g. using Developer Tools / F12) and check that your script, which uses `PrimeFaces` var, is placed *after* the `core.js`. If it's not the case, move the script to another place in your source file. E.g. just before the `</body>` tag.